# phpstorm replace array() notation to [ ] short syntax

Tags: regex, replace, phpstorm

I would like to transform all "array(...)" notation in "[...]" in my project but I don't find a regex that work for all cases.

Do you have something that work for all cases (nested array, array on multiple lines, nested array on multiple lines)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

1. `Code | Inspect Code...` --- run it on your files. One of the inspections called **"Traditional syntax array literal detected"**.

   Alternatively just run that specific inspection only via `Code | Run Inspection by Name...`
2. Once done, you will see a list with results. Find that particular inspection in results (in case if 1st option was used (all inspections)).
3. From there you can apply "Fix it" action on all (or individual) results of that inspection.

**P.S.** This inspection/fix available since PhpStorm v7.1.

[image]

Comment: Works still the same in PhpStorm 10

Comment: Great answer. Works with PHPstorm v9 as well.

Comment: Works in 2016.1 after configuring as defined here: http://typo3-development.nl/on-the-side-table/phpstorm-short-hand-syntax-for-arrays/

Comment: @LazyOne My project uses PHP 5.3 which does not respect the new short array syntax. Is there a way to do the opposite of what you described above?

Comment: @lesssugar Telling IDE to not to use it when generating new code -- yes, in Code Style for PHP (there is a check box option). Converting back to traditional style (like the actions in my answer) -- no. But you should setup Code Style first (in case if it's not done already) and try `Code | Reformat Code...` (and use it on selected code) -- see if it will do such transformation there.

Comment: Make sure "Traditional syntax array literal detected" is enabled in Inspection Settings.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA, it's in `Analyze | Inspect Code...`, need to enable `Traditional syntax array literal detected` in the preference `Editor | Code Style | Inspection | PHP | Code style`

Comment: @lesssugar, did you find the smart way to convert `[]` into `array()`?

Answer (score 34):

Open File->Settings...
Click Editor->Code Style->PHP->Code Conversion

Now you can find block "Array declaration style" at the bottom.

If you check checkbox "Force short declaration style" your "array(...)" became "[...]" when you run Reformat code (Ctrl+Shift+L).

Comment: Great answer! Thanks

Comment: Thank you. You can click on a folder in the project and run the format code shortcut and it will do all of the files in the folder

Answer (score 19):

As of now (PHPStorm 2017.3.2) it is here: 
`Settings/Editor/Code Style/PHP/Code Conversion/Array Declaration style`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to update a single array/line, you can place the cursor on the array and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to invoke the **intention actions** dialogue then select the *Convert array to short syntax* option. <sup>[1](https://phpstorm.tips/tips/17-convert-arrays/)</sup>

[image: animated gif from phpstorm tips]